# find the range of a function 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

> Find the range of function
>   $$f(x)= \log_2(|e^x-\sinh(x)|+\lfloor \frac{2+x^2}{1+x^2} \rfloor)$$
>   and find $f([0,3\rangle)$.

So far what I've got is:

$$e^x-\sinh(x)=e^x-\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}=\cosh(x)$$

$$|\cosh(x)|=\cosh(x), \forall x \in \Bbb R$$

$$\lfloor \frac{2+x^2}{1+x^2} \rfloor = \lfloor 1+ \frac{1}{1+x^2} \rfloor=1+ \lfloor\frac{1}{1+x^2} \rfloor$$

Now I didn't really know what to do so I went to find the domain because I thought it would maybe help me to see how to find the range.

$$f(x)=\log_2(\cosh(x)+1+\lfloor\frac{1}{1+x^2} \rfloor)$$

1. $$1+x^2 \neq 0,  \forall x \in \Bbb R$$
2. $$\cosh(x)+1+\lfloor\frac{1}{1+x^2} \rfloor >0$$

Now, all values of $\cosh(x)$ are $\ge 1$, and all values of $\cosh(x)+1$ are $\ge 2$. That means that, for the previous inequality to be true, $\lfloor\frac{1}{1+x^2} \rfloor$ has to be $\gt-2$, that is, $\frac{1}{1+x^2} \ge -1$. This also is true $\forall x \in \Bbb R$.

So the domain for $f(x)$ is $\Bbb R$, but I'm still stuck. How do I find the range of ths function?